# NSNumberFormatter, localized setGroupingSeparator?

Tags: objective-c, ios, cocoa-touch

With NSNumberFormatter it is very easy to format a number using a fixed string as GroupingSeparator.

```
[numberFormatter setGroupingSeparator:@"."];
```

But in some countries @"." is not the valid separator: @"," (a comma) is instead. How can I get a localized grouping separator from the system so my formatting is correct all around the world in any language?

Answer (score 7, accepted):

You can use [`setLocale:`](http://developer.apple.com/library/mac/documentation/Cocoa/Reference/Foundation/Classes/NSNumberFormatter_Class/Reference/Reference.html#//apple_ref/doc/uid/20000202-CJBIGCCE):

```
[numberFormatter setLocale:[NSLocale currentLocale]];
```

The locale exposes the correct symbols for things like decimal separator, quotation marks, and units of measurement and currency.

However! Beware of using this for currency; there is no automatic *value* conversion. If you have a number representing some amount of U.S. dollars, and just format it as if it were euros, it will be formatted correctly, but will not have the correct meaning.

Comment: This should be obvious (but I made this mistake anyway): the formatter's numberStyle property also needs to be set to something other than NSNumberFormatterNoStyle.

Comment: I am just curious why is that necessary? Shouldn't formatters automatically have locally set from current locale? If not - whys is that so?

Comment: Yes, it does, @Lukasz, but as I read it, the OP's problem here was correctly formatting things for locales other than the device's current one.